# How to run a php file by double clicking?

Tags: php

Is there any way to run a php file by a shortcut in hard drive?..not by writing any protocol in the browser. 
I am making an online examination system in PHP. And I using Wampserver. I want to run my first page from a shortcut(like html), from then other linked pages will run sequentially.thanks in advance....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First Copy your local url from browser `http://localhost/xxx/xxx.php`

Then go to your desktop press `Right click in Mouse choose -> New -> Shortcut`.

Now paste copied Link then press `next` and `finish` button shortcut ready.

Then copy that shortcut and paste it in anywhere.

Comment: hey this will automatically run in browser.

Answer (score 2):

If your wampserver is on, you can place this `meta` HTML tag in your `.html` file:

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://localhost/index.php">
```

It's an HTML way of redirecting, `content` is the number of seconds after which you want the redirect to take place and `url` is the location you want to redirect to.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Html file with name `XXX.html`

Create a file of `XXX.html` at any drive you want

and put this code in html:

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://localhost/yourproject/xxx.php">
```

Now you will able to change **Icon** of HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

Simple.

Just create batch with the command

```
php.exe location/to/my/script.php
pause
```

And then, just double click the batch file and run it.

However, you have to add php.exe to your system path variable. It can be more dynamic. Please refer to this link to watch a video tutorial on it.

[[VIDEO] How to double-click & run PHP in CMD/console?](http://tanmayonrun.blogspot.com/2016/04/How-to-double-click-and-run-PHP-in-CMD-or-console.html)